# Getting null value while using @Query of spring data from mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have been querying mongodb using mongorepository and spring data.

My function looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User,String> {
    @Query(value="{'email' : ?0}")
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

My collection in mongodb looks like this

```
> db.user.find();
{ "_id" : "1", "email" : "abc@gmail.com", "password" : "$2a$12$lDJgMZNLAcxv2J.QTZSjAuWJdPleBxXq.M4aj9itrR1RMDkgmwN7m", "name" : "def", "active" : 1, "isLoacked" : false, "isExpired" : false, "isEnabled" : true, "_class" : "com.x.gateway.auth.User" }
```

It always returns null value.

Comment: which email are you use for query ?

Comment: email :abc@gmail.com

Comment: Try to use List<User> may be email is not a unique field at all.

Comment: @AbinashGhosh Your suggestion worked
`
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User,String> {
    //@Query(value="{'email' : ?0}")
    List<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
`
Thanks man. Now will try to make the field unique. If you got any cheatsheet on db schema standards in mongo please attach it would be great help in this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `email` is not a unique property, multiple users can be fetched. So map the method to `List<User>`.

```
@Query(value="{'email' : ?0}")
List<User> findByEmail(String email);
```

[Offical doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html), here you can find more details.

Comment: In official doc   `6.3 Query methods` is all about different query method.

Comment: if you find any solution helpful try to upvote it also

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using

```
@Query(value="{'email' : ?0}")
```

As email is the direct field (Not nested) , only

```
User findByEmail(String email);
```

is enough and should work.

Comment: @Alien :  i had commented the annotation still no luck

Comment: @AbinashGhosh : i had used email :abc@gmail.com for querying

Comment: Ok then check you have only one record with this email in your db + Repository is autowired properly in service or controller class.